# DrawString and padding... again?

Tags: c#

in my path learning c# I encountered a problem in using DrawString in one of the most obvious ways (at least I thought, well I think that still now): left alignment.

If I have to print several lines one below the other, with different sized fonts, they are not perfectly aligned at the left position but there is always some white space.

I know, this thing was asked a ton of times already, and countless sites examine it, but unfortunately I was not able to find any working real solution.

Here it is my homework:

```
int x = 2480;
int y = 3508;
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(x, y);
bmp.SetResolution(300, 300);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.White);
```

A simple representation of an A4 paper sheet. Nothing to see here.

They said, add this:

```
g.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAliasGridFit;
```

or other similar anti alias stuff - verdict: USELESS.

They said, use a nice string format:

```
StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
sf.Trimming = StringTrimming.None;
```

with a lot of fancy flags - verdict: USELESS.

Here they are, the ones:

```
SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
Font f32 = new Font("Arial", 32);
g.DrawString("Company name", f32, b, 0, 0, sf);
Font f14 = new Font("Arial", 14);
g.DrawString("Address somewhere", f14, b, 0, 100, sf);
```

They said, also, use another way:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.NoClipping | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;
TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "Company name", f32, r, Color.Black, flags);
```

With a lot of flags in various combinations - verdict: USELESS.

A lot of posts/sites say: use MeasureString.
Great, when I have that mythical "measure" what should I do with it?
If I try to use a Rectangle with that measure for enclosing the string, nothing is displayed, probably because there is no room for that white space around the string

Any help appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: If you use `StringAlignment` correctly, it should work. So you've most likely used it incorrectly. But it's not possible to help unless you provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Comment: Peter, the code above is the code of my procedure, just interleaved with comments. Apart the last block when I say it is an alternate path. I will post a complete procedure. Anyway the code just does not print in the exact position but always adds extra space above and at left of characters - officially for the "glyphs", well here there are no glyphs so it has no sense.